# Destructuring of es6 but passing dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

Says my `state` is like this:

```
{
  item:{
      a:'a',
      b:'b'
  }
}
```

Then I'm able to pull `a` from item by doing:

`const { a } = this.state.item`

but can pull dynamically using `{}` of `es6` ?

For example `const { variable } = this.state.item`, where `variable` can be `a` or `b`.

Comment: You can't re-define a `const` to have a different value. What variable should hold the output? I looks like you will need [computed property destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As [4castle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5743988/4castle) pointet out, you could use [Computed object property names and destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring) with an additional key/value pair variables for destructuring.

```js
var object = { item: { a: 'a0', b: 'b0' } },
    key = 'b',
    value;

({ [key]: value } = object.item);

console.log(value);
```

Comment: this is way too complicated, i rather just do if else and assign it to a normal variable.

Comment: you asked for destructuring. the rest is up to you.

Comment: @AlexYong Destructuring will only make sense if you need to do this with more than one property at a time. Otherwise, you might as well do `const value = object.item[key];`

Comment: Exactly how to use a variable when destructuring 

Answer (score 1):

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const { [name]: property, ...rest } = coupon;
        setNewValue({ [name]: value, ...rest });
    }
```